# Add a conditional row in crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am working on a C# app that will print bills/receipts with a thermal printer. I am using **Crystal Reports** for generating reports/bills.

I want the report to have 4 fields (Item Name, Quantity, Amount, Discount). There might be a discount sometimes otherwise not. The format of this report should be something like this (For reference also see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3qlW.jpg))

```
| Item Name | Qty | Amount$ |
|---------------------------|
| Abc       |  1  |  100    |
| You Saved 4$    |         |
|---------------------------|
| Def       |  1  |  50     |
|---------------------------|
```

As from the table, there was a discount for Item = Abc, so the discount row (You saved 4$) is there, for the Item=Def there was no discount so the row is not there.

#### How can i achieve a result like this?

#### Edit Solved.

Comment: We need to see your relevant code snippet and your best attempt at resolving this yourself.  Are you getting an error?  Or is the output not as you expect?  Please edit your question and add details.

Comment: it is more of a design thing, i just need some pointers on whats this(the thing i want) is actually called. There was a cross tab option in crystal reports, but i dont cross-tab is releated to what i want.

Comment: @huzaifa99 consider change you SQL query for (*instead a column called "Discount"*) the value of "Discount" is added as a line break in the "Item Name" column (*when a discount exists*) - and do as devlin carnate told you: `add your relevant code snippet and your best attempt at resolving this yourself`, otherwise, as is your question, it's very difficult to add ideas and more accurate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for an additional column.
Right-click the detail section and select 'Insert Section Below.
This should result in Detail a (where you place the normal content) and Detail b section (where you place the discount info.

In the Suppress expression for Detail b have an expression such as:

```
{Discount} = 0
```

That would cause that section to be visible only when Discount is not zero.

Comment: Here is what the result looks like, ignore the values they are all dummy.  https://pdfhost.io/edit?doc=fe33a0b0-c809-4472-951b-e81a5999b8e6

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the complete answer to your case, but it generally is applicable and give you an idea.

You can conditionally suppress the band.
I think you pass the dataset to the report. If so, add a new column to your dataset. for each row, that column should define if the band needs to be suppressed or not. and use that column in your condition for suppressing the band.