# Group by multiple bit or conditionally render using crystal and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports

I have a table where I have students name, their ID and a bit to signify whether or not they passed a certain subject. Ultimately, I would like to group by all the subjects in 1 report / query where individuals have passed.
I couldnt figure out how to script this so I just did a `select *` and elected to try in crystal reports.

This is my Data.

| ID | Name | passMath | passScience | passFrench |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | John | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Kacy | 0 | 1 | 1 |

And this is the expected results, or what I am ultimately trying to show in a report. Basically, in my crystal report, I'll have a secion
**Math**

Peter

**Science**

John

Kacy

**French**

Peter

John

Kacy

**What have I tried**

Now, I haven't figured out how to do this in a query, so what I did is, following the answer from this link I tried to [conditionally render a section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64811666/add-a-conditional-row-in-crystal-report).

My issue is, this sort of works but the results it's returning is.

**passMath**

Peter

passScience

John

**passMath**

John

Basically, instead of grouping everyone who passed math together, it's giving them their separate row. So John and Peter both create a section titled "passMath" where I want them to be grouped together. What I did in crystal report was to create a section>section expert and add `{usp_student.passMath}=  false` to the formula area where I expect it to suppress all records that didnt pass Math. So far it works 50% And I would like it to group them all.

Appreciate if I could get help with this query or a way to fix the crystal report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but I suspect it may help:

```
with subjects as (
  select * from (values('Math'), ('Science'), ('French'))s(Subject)
)
select Subject, Name 
from Subjects s
join t on 
    (s.subject = 'Math' and t.passMath = 1) or
    (s.subject = 'Science' and t.passScience = 1) or
    (s.subject = 'French' and t.passFrench = 1)
order by Subject;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resort to the type of cartesian product suggested by Stu, two alternatives are:

1. Use a UNION statement to concatenate the passing cases for the 3 scenarios.

Or

2. In Crystal, simply insert 3 subreports, each showing the students passing one of the targeted subjects.

Comment: Could you tell me why not? I as working on something like that before his answer.

Comment: All of these approaches are valid. The alternatives I suggested may be easier to understand/maintain.